# if else is not working in opengl langauge

Tags: java, css, web

I am using this code on opengl script

but when i use if else conditoin it not works , every time i run script it choose the first value of color variable which is declared before if else.

```
float color = 0.3 * clr.r + 0.59 * clr.g + 0.11 * clr.b; // script always choose this value instead of if else values

float maxrgb = max(max(clr.r, clr.g), clr.b);

if (maxrgb < 128.0) {
  float color = 0.21 * clr.r + 0.71 * clr.g + 0.80 * clr.b;
} else if (maxrgb > 128.0) {
  float color = 0.30 * clr.r + 0.60 * clr.g + 0.82 * clr.b;
} // the values in the condition are not working.
```

is am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: usually when you read `clr.r` you get a normalized number between 0.0 and 1.0.  So it will always be < 128.0.  You probably meant to put `0.5` instead of `128.0`

Comment: You don't need to nest calls to `max()`. It takes any number of arguments.

Comment: @smallbee Read the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared the `color` variable twice. You have declared a new variable with the same name in scope of the `if`-statement. Declare the variable before the if statement, but assign new values to the existing variable in the statement:

```c
float color = 0.3 * clr.r + 0.59 * clr.g + 0.11 * clr.b; 

float maxrgb = max(max(clr.r, clr.g), clr.b);

if (maxrgb < 128.0) {
    color = 0.21 * clr.r + 0.71 * clr.g + 0.80 * clr.b;
} else if (maxrgb > 128.0) {
    color = 0.30 * clr.r + 0.60 * clr.g + 0.82 * clr.b;
}
```